# Expressiong $\frac{t+2}{t^3+3}$ in the form $a_o+a_1t+...+a_4t^4$, where $t$ is a root of $x^5+2x+2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Expressing $\frac{t+2}{t^3+3}$ in the form $a_o+a_1t+...+a_4t^4$, where $t$ is a root of $x^5+2x+2$.

So i can deal with the numerator, but how do I get rid of the denomiator to get it into the correct form? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Euclidean algorithm for computing $\gcd(x^3+3,x^5+2x+2)$, we get
$$
367=(10 x^4 - 31 x^3 - 14 x^2 - 30 x + 113)(x^3+3)+(-10 x^2 + 31 x + 14)(x^5+2x+2)
$$
and so
$$
367=(10 t^4 - 31 t^3 - 14 t^2 - 30 t + 113)(t^3+3)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
367\frac{t+2}{t^3+3}
&=(t+2)(10 t^4 - 31 t^3 - 14 t^2 - 30 t + 113)\\
&=10(t^5+2t+2)+(-11 t^4 - 76 t^3 - 58 t^2 + 33 t + 206)\\
&=-11 t^4 - 76 t^3 - 58 t^2 + 33 t + 206
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \left(   x^{3}  + 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{4}  - 31 x^{3}  - 14 x^{2}  - 30 x  + 113 }{ 367 } \right) \equiv 1 \pmod {   x^{5}  + 2 x  + 2 }   $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(   x^{5}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  \right) } +  \left(   - 3 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   - 3 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 3 x  - 2 }{ 9 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 10 x  + 31 }{ 9 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   - 3 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 10 x  + 31 }{ 9 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 270 x  + 1017 }{ 100 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ -3303}{100 } \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{ 10 x  + 31 }{ 9 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ -3303}{100 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 1000 x  - 3100 }{ 29727 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 3 x  - 2 }{ 9 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 3 x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 9 }{ 9 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 3 x  - 2 }{ 9 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 270 x  + 1017 }{ 100 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 90 x^{4}  - 279 x^{3}  - 126 x^{2}  - 270 x  + 1017 }{ 100 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 90 x^{2}  - 279 x  - 126 }{ 100 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 1000 x  - 3100 }{ 29727 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 100 x^{5}  - 200 x  - 200 }{ 3303 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 100 x^{3}  - 300 }{ 3303 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{2}  - 31 x  - 14 }{ 367 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{4}  - 31 x^{3}  - 14 x^{2}  - 30 x  + 113 }{ 367 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

Comment: Thank you so much for writing all this up. I figured it was the euclidean algorithm but I was hoping there was a slicker quicker way.