# Finding $(t^3+3)^{-1}$ if $t^5+2t+2=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Finding $(t^3+3)^{-1}$ if $t^5+2t+2=0$.

I started trying to do this one by the euclidean algorithm but I wasn't able to get the remainder down to a unit. Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Is this in an arbitrary ring?

Comment: same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958566/expressiong-fract2t33-in-the-form-a-oa-1t-a-4t4-where-t-is which I did with the Euclidean algorithm with rational coefficients

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut $$ \left(   x^{3}  + 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{4}  - 31 x^{3}  - 14 x^{2}  - 30 x  + 113 }{ 367 } \right) \equiv 1 \pmod {   x^{5}  + 2 x  + 2 }   $$

Comment: @Will What if the coef ring is a field of characteristic $367?$  Hence Carl's question.

Comment: @BillDubuque a fair point. For this OP, I am confident the coefficients are the reals, which we can reduce to the rationals. I am also wondering if the OP understands that the units are the (nonzero) constants; also, when $t^5 + 2t + 2 = 0,$ has he tried to find anything computationally easier such as $\frac{1}{t}?$

Comment: @Will fyi: they have a common factor $\large t+260$ over $\,\Bbb F_{\large 367}\,$ so $\large t^3+3$ has no inverse there.

Comment: @Will Any idea of the source? If the point was to teach the extended Euclidean algorithm for polynomials then surely one could give much less painful examples amenable to hand computation. So there must be more to it than that.

Comment: @Bill no idea. A few days ago he asked about $(t+2)/ (t^3 + 3)$ given $t^5 + 2 t + 2 = 0,$ and two of us gave the same answer, one was accepted. Maybe he is self studying out of a problem book. I seem to recall him writing that his regular classes were boring; maybe that is on Main somewhere, it was not long ago.